# How to check if nested model created new record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

I have classes below:

```
class Level1
   has_many :level2s
   has_many :level3s

   after_create :get_new_record_of_saved_level3
end

class Level2
   belongs_to :level1
   belongs_to :level3
end

class Level3
   has_many :level2s
   has_many :level1s
end
```

If I call level1.save, level2.save and level3.save will be called before. How can I get the saved level3 if it is new record in the call_back of level1?

Comment: You can get by `Level1.last.level3s` but what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I think Level1.last is not right because maybe many users create Level1 object at the same time.

Comment: You need to call this method `after_create_and_commit` call back. You will always get last record no matter how many users create `Level1` . because all request goes in sequence.

Comment: Why use after_create_and_commit always get last record of Level1.last? Is it the same matter if many users create object at same time.

Comment: def    get_new_record_of_saved_level3  self.level3.new_record?
end

Comment: @TusharPal I am sorry. But self.level3.new_record? return false because level3 is saved into db before self saved.